# How do I handle a freelancing project thats budgets low to my standard

Tags: freelance-websites

I have this freelancing project but the budget given doesn't meets the requirements to get the job done on time, how do I handle such situations?

Comment: Welcome. // Did you start already?

Comment: Done on time or done at all ?

Comment: No I haven't due to client's low budget

Comment: It's also my first project as a freelancer

Comment: Is it 'fixed price' or 'pay as you go by the hour' ?

Comment: There are a lot of "clients" who think that what they want won't cost much. I've heard that of 10 people who want something done, only 2-3 can actually afford it. Find those people and let the rest go.

Comment: Yea I get it now

Comment: It's a fixed price

Comment: Ask for more money and given itemized reasons why you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You‘ve got several options, like:

1. Discuss this with your client and negotiate better conditions. Take your taxes etc. into account.
2. Refuse it.
3. Do it for charity. Make that clear to your prospect.

Don‘t be afraid, there will be more people you can serve. Which you can‘t, when you bound your resources for nothing.

Comment: that's the reply I wanted REFUSE IT

Answer (score 0):

> budget given doesn't meets the requirements to get the job done on time

Then you **refuse** the project. Or ask for what you *do* need.

No one states you *must* accept *any* offer. Thinking you "have to" is folly.

Answer (score 0):

**Negotiating is contract rather than just accepting/rejecting it**
Being hired by a client is a two-way negotiation: it is okay to clarify that you expect to be paid more for the urgency or that working on the project would take longer that the client proposes.

**Knowing yourself**
An important part is knowing what concessions you can make and how far you can go in this. If the conditions are plain unacceptable, you just say *No*. However, there might be other motivations, besides money and timing, for taking the project - e.g., to maintain relationship with a long-term client, getting the door open to a profitable sector, not staying completely without work, etc. These have to be taken into account - e.g., admitting that you are not worth (at the moment) as much as you think you are worth is a hard pill; but this may be temporary, and you may start getting paid more as you gain reputation, permanent clients, experience, etc.

**Reading the client**
From the other side, it is always a matter of guessing, how much client is willing to pay and how fast they really expect the work done. There are different types of clients: some have really low budget, others do not really know what they want or how fast they need it, some may be simply shopping for an "intelligent guy" for whom they could later give more work.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working as a freelancer for 12 years. Let me tell you that if you think this project will give you learning opportunity then don't think about the budget at all. Just do it and gain experience and add it to your profile. Almost every freelancer start working on projects with a low rate just to win the competition and when they have enough experience and feedback they start getting a lot of job offers then they can adjust the rate of the projects and negotiate.

But if you think it is not the case for you then you can explain your client the complication of the project (why the budget should be higher) or you can tell them the quality of your work (the features of you that make you better than the rest of the freelancers who offers a cheap rate). There are clients who would understand and allow renegotiation.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have been working as a freelancer for the past 3 years. One important thing to remember when you're just starting out is that you might need to accept lower pay for your work.

As you build your reputation in the freelancing field, you'll have the choice to take on lower-paying projects. You can find people who are willing to do the work for less money, give them the project, and oversee its progress.

I have done many projects in this way and will do them by myself only strong offers projects maybe my answer is helpful or not but it's just my own way of working.

2nd is you can accept offer in less but through your communication skills and work quality with new suggestions request to increase offer .

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with a freelancing project when the budget doesn't seem sufficient can be challenging, but it's essential to navigate these situations professionally and effectively. Here's a step-by-step approach to handle such situations:

**Evaluate the Scope:** First, make sure you have a clear understanding of the project's scope and requirements. Double-check if your assessment aligns with the budget provided. Sometimes, the scope might be more extensive than you initially thought.

**Communicate with the Client:** Reach out to your client promptly and professionally. Express your concerns about the budget and the potential impact on the project's quality or timeline. Use polite and constructive language. Explain what the budget limitations mean in terms of the project's deliverables and timeframe.

**Offer Solutions:** Instead of just highlighting the problem, propose potential solutions. These could include:

**Adjusting the scope:** Suggest reducing the project's scope to fit within the budget while maintaining its core objectives.

**Phasing the project:** Propose breaking the project into smaller phases that can be completed within the given budget, with additional phases to be considered later.

**Negotiating an increase in the budget:** Politely inquire if the client is open to revisiting the budget to better match the project's requirements.

**Provide Alternatives:** If the client is unwilling or unable to increase the budget, offer alternative approaches that might be more cost-effective. For example, using existing templates, tools, or resources that can save time and money.

**Consider Your Limits:** Be clear about your own limitations. Determine the minimum budget you would need to complete the project satisfactorily. If the client cannot meet this minimum, you may need to decline the project to avoid taking on something that may not be financially viable.

**Document Everything:** Keep records of all communication with the client regarding the budget discussions. This can be essential for resolving disputes or clarifying expectations later on.

**Make a Decision:** Based on the client's response and your own assessment, make a decision about whether you can proceed with the project within the given constraints. If you can't reach a reasonable agreement and you believe the project won't be successful within the budget, it might be best to decline the project politely.

Remember that clear communication and professionalism are key in handling these situations. It's important to maintain a positive relationship with the client, even if you cannot reach an agreement on the budget. This can help preserve your reputation and potentially lead to future opportunities when circumstances allow for a better budget match.